# Make a UITextView expand AND moving down the other objects

Tags: ios, textview

I have a `UITableView`. In every cell I have a `UITextView` with variable length.
I'd like that `UITextView` expands to fit all the text.

```
[UITextView sizeToFit];
```

doesn't work.
Also, I need that its expanding moves down the other labels and objects in the cell (and the height of the cell must change, of course).
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to declare delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and then use this code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat rowHeight;
    NSString *text1 = [arrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //your text
    CGRect frame = [text1 boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(160, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]}
                                      context:nil];  // here get the height of ur textline

   CGSize size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height+1);
    rowHeight=size.height*2;

    return rowHeight;
}
```

Hope this code may be very helpful to you and you can easily implement it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update frame of each view depending on frame of uitextview

here is what i m trying to say, its just a sample you had modify the frame of all next views

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tblCell"];
    UITextView *txt = [cell viewWithTag:1];
    txt.text  =[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [txt sizeToFit];

    CGRect frame = txt.frame;
    CGRect frame2;

    UILabel *lbl  = [cell viewWithTag:2];
    frame2 = lbl.frame;
    if(frame.size.width + frame2.size.width >= cell.frame.size.width){
        frame2.origin.x = 0;
        frame2.origin.y += frame.size.height;
        [lbl setFrame:frame2];
    }
    else{
        frame2.origin.x = frame.size .width;
        [lbl setFrame:frame2];
    }
return cell;

}
```